# I want to get the result with multiple mysql db using spring

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

i want to get the result which are got two different DB using spring-boot but i got the error now Actually i can't find what is wrong..

VO.Dve code

```
package com.example.rest.VO;


import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "MART")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Dve {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private String USER_ID;
    private Integer ID;


    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }
}
```

VO.LogVo

```
package com.example.rest.VO;


import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

@Entity
@Table(name = "log")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class LogVo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private String put_date;
    private Integer SCNT;
    private Integer SENT_TOTAL;
    private Integer SCART;
    private Integer ST_TOTAL;
    private Integer Imby_tables_cnt;
    private Integer Alarm;
    private Integer Alert;
    private Integer Watch;
    private Integer TZ;
    private Integer Normal;
    private Integer Rating_sum;


    public Integer getSENT_TOTAL(){
        return SENT_TOTAL;
    }
}
```

RestDbConfig

```
package com.example.rest;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement

@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
        basePackages = {"com.example.rest.rec.repo"}
)



public class RestDbConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "db1.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
    entityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource
    )
    {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.example.rest.rec.domain").persistenceUnit("resystem").build();
        }

        @Primary
        @Bean(name = "trasactionManager")
        public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory)
        {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
        }

}
```

RidDbConfig

```
package com.example.rest;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "ridEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "ridTransactionManager",
        basePackages = {"com.example.rest.rid.repository.repo"}
)

public class RidDbConfig {
    @Bean(name = "ridDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "ridEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean ridEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
             @Qualifier("ridDataSource") DataSource dataSource
    )
    {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.example.rest.rid.repository.domain").persistenceUnit("rid").build();
    }

    @Bean(name="ridTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager ridTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("ridEntityManagerFactory")EntityManagerFactory ridEntityManagerFactory
            )
    {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(ridEntityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

EmpRepository1

```
package com.example.rest.rid.repository.repo;
import com.example.rest.VO.LogVo;
import com.example.rest.rid.repository.domain.R1pro;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface EmpRepository1 extends JpaRepository<LogVo, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "select * from dt.log order by put_date DESC limit 1",nativeQuery = true)
    public List<R1pro> findByLimit();
}
```

R1pro

```
package com.example.rest.rid.repository.domain;


public interface R1pro {
    String getSENT_TOTAL();
}
```

EmpRepository2

```
package com.example.rest.rec.repo;
import com.example.rest.VO.Dve;
import com.example.rest.rec.domain.R2pro;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface EmpRepository2 extends JpaRepository<Dve, String> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT user_id FROM MART limit 1",nativeQuery = true)
    public List<R2pro> findByLimit1();
}
```

R2pro

```
package com.example.rest.rec.domain;


public interface R2pro {
    String getUSER_ID();
}
```

EmpController1

```
package com.example.rest.controller;


import com.example.rest.rec.repo.EmpRepository2;
import com.example.rest.rid.repository.domain.R1pro;
import com.example.rest.rec.domain.R2pro;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.example.rest.rid.repository.repo.EmpRepository1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/emp")

public class EmpController1 {
    @Autowired
    private EmpRepository1 empRepository1;
    private EmpRepository2 empRepository2;

    @Autowired
public EmpController1(EmpRepository1 empRepository, EmpRepository2 empRepository2) {
    this.empRepository1 = empRepository1;
    this.empRepository2 = empRepository2;
}

    @RequestMapping(value="/ee", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String getCategoryList() {
        R1pro r1pro = empRepository1.findByLimit();

        return r1pro.getSENT_TOTAL();
    }



    @Autowired
    @RequestMapping(value = "/ef",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String getgiem(){
        R2pro r2pro =empRepository2.findByLimit1();

        return r2pro.getUSER_ID();
    }
}
```

Application

```
package com.example.rest;
import com.example.rest.rid.repository.repo.EmpRepository1;
import com.example.rest.rec.repo.EmpRepository2;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }


}
```

So when i run the code i got the this error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'empController1' defined in file [C:\Users\DS-18-D3-023\Desktop\data-migration-new-indicator\springboottutorial\target\classes\com\example\rest\controller\EmpController1.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'empRepository2': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.rest.VO.Dve
```

What is wrong..it please teach me

Also the all of the VO is correct columns 
when i run the code separate is working very well

all error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'empController1' defined in file [C:\Users\DS-18-D3-023\Desktop\data-migration-new-indicator\springboottutorial\target\classes\com\example\rest\controller\EmpController1.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'empRepository1': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.rest.VO.LogVo
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:732) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:197) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1276) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1133) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at com.example.rest.Application.main(Application.java:12) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'empRepository1': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.rest.VO.LogVo
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1708) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
... 24 common frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.rest.VO.LogVo
at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:473) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:73) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:181) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:119) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:102) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:298) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$3(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:287) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:290) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:102) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1767) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1704) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
... 35 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Can you remove the `@Autowired` from `public String getgiem()` ? And annotate the `private EmpRepository2 empRepository2;` instead.

Comment: Now i did it but i got the same error

Comment: '@Autowired' not applicable to type i gotit

Comment: Oops, I've just seen that you're using `@Autowired` both on fields and constructor. You either use it on fields or constructor. And the `JpaRepository` second argument needs to be the id type. In your case `String` for both repositories.

Comment: no R1pro is got the Integet so i need one Integer and one String

Comment: Can you paste the entire stack error in your post please?

Comment: yes sure!~ i did it

Comment: If you're using `@Autowired` on the constructor, you need one more parameter (EmpRepository1 empRepository1) ( look at 1) from my answer )

Comment: Could you tell me more specific?!

Comment: Modify `public EmpController1(EmpRepository2 empRepository2)` to `public EmpController1(EmpRepository2 empRepository2, EmpRepository1 empRepository1)`

Comment: OHHH normally i included but  when i typed in here it was skipped anyway Thank you

Comment: Did it solved your problem?

Comment: No... original script has already inclueded..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207824/discussion-between-sebastian-csvean-and-hognkun).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Repository
public interface EmpRepository1 extends JpaRepository<LogVo, String> {

@Query(value = "select * from dt.log order by put_date DESC limit 1",nativeQuery = true)
public List<R1pro> findByLimit();
}
```

In EmpRepository1.java **change JpaRepository to JpaRepository** as id in Entity of type String

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are some major problems with your code:

1) `@Autowired` from controller both on fields and constructor - you either use it on fields, either on constructor (I suggest you to use it on the constructor since the controller isn't useful without the repositories) and you need one more parameter `EmpRepository1 empRepository1`

**Solution:**

```
private EmpRepository1 empRepository1;
private EmpRepository2 empRepository2;

@Autowired
public EmpController1(EmpRepository2 empRepository2, EmpRepository1 empRepository1) {
    this.empRepository1 = empRepository1;
    this.empRepository2 = empRepository2;
}
```

2) `@Autowired` from `public String getgiem()` (This is not correct)

**Solution:** remove the annotation

3) Repository's method return type `R2Pro` or `R1Pro` . Once you're extending `JpaRepository` be aware that the generic interface is `JpaRepository<T,ID>` and every method expects either void, either `T` return type.

**Solution:** change the return type expected in your methods:

*ORIGINAL:*

```
@Query(value = "SELECT user_id FROM MART limit 1",nativeQuery = true)
public List<R2pro> findByLimit1();
```

*MODIFIED:*

```
@Repository
public interface EmpRepository2 extends JpaRepository<Dve, String> {

@Query(value = "SELECT user_id FROM MART limit 1",nativeQuery = true)
public List<Dve> findByLimit1(); // List<Dve> return type.
}
```

And the `@Id` annotated field type needs to be the same in `EmpRepository1` (`String`)
    *ORIGINAL:*

```
@Query(value = "select * from dt.log order by put_date DESC limit 1",nativeQuery = true)
public List<R1pro> findByLimit();
```

*MODIFIED:*

```
@Repository
public interface EmpRepository1 extends JpaRepository<LogVo, String> {

@Query(value = "select * from dt.log order by put_date DESC limit 1",nativeQuery = true)
public List<LogVo> findByLimit();
}
```

**P.S.** : You can use non-primitive data types like `Integer` , `Long` etc. if your query looks like *"SELECT user_id FROM MART limit 1"* ( only in case that you don't need the entire object )

e.g. :

```
@Query(value = "SELECT user_id FROM MART limit 1",nativeQuery = true)
public List<String> findByLimit1(); // the user_id is of String type
}
```

And once you use `limit 1` in your query, it means that you're expecting only one result, not a list. So the `List<>` isn't necessary.

Comment: I don't understand  change the return type expected in your methods:

Comment: how can i do that?/

Comment: I've provided solutions for problems. You need to change your original code with the code from my answer.